# Is $K[X]/(f)$ an algebraic extension?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

If $K$ a field and $f\in K[X]$ is irreducible, is $K[X]/(f)$ always algebraic? Those fields look strange to me. Indeed, for example, $\mathbb C=\mathbb R[X]/(X^2+1)$, but $\mathbb C$ are number whereas element of $\mathbb R[X]/(X^2+1)$ seem to be polynomials. So I'm a little bit perturbed.

So for my exercise, I have to show that if $x\in K[X]/(f)$ then there is a polynomial $g(T)\in  K[X]/(f)[T]$ s.t. $g(x)=0$ right? How?

Comment: Some help is that if $f,g\in \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$ and $f=g$ implies that $f-g\in (x^2+1)$ which means that $f-g=p(x^2+1)$ for some $p\in \mathbb{R}[x]$. This means that we have that $f\cong ax+b$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, but what can $x$ be equivalent to? The 0 in our $x^2+1$ which is $i$, which means it is isomorphic to complex numbers. You shouldn't write equal to them, but isomorphic to them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for $K$ a field and $f\in K[X]$ for  irreducible then $K[X]/(f)$ is a field and this field is an algebraic extension of $K$.

For $\mathbb R[X]/(X^2+1)$ the elements are in fact equivalence classes (so sets) of polynomials. (Recall congruence modulo $n$, for a similar situation.) However, from each class/element you can chose one representative which has degree at most $1$ (for any polynomial consider the remainder on polynomial division by $X^2 + 1$), so the elements of this field are the classes of $a + bX$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, thus they are parametrized by pairs of real numbers. The correspondence to $\mathbb{C}$ is given by $a+ b X \mapsto a+bi$. It still needs to be shown that this is well-defined and compatible with the operations. To appreciate this informally note that $X^2$ divided by $X^2  +1$ leaves rest $-1$ so $X^2$ is (in the same class as ) $-1$.

More generally, the elements of $K[X]/(f)$ can be thought of polynomial expressions of degree at most $\deg (f) -1$. The "variable" in these polynomial expression is precisely a root of $f$.

Yes, to show that the extension field  $K[X]/(f)$ is algebraic over $K$ what you have to do  would be to show that for each element  $A \in K[X]/(f)$ there is a polynomial $f \in K [T]$ such that $f(A)$.

To do this effectively you can note that that the class of $X$ is a root of $f$, essentially by definition. Then, note that the sum and product of algebraic numbers is algebraic and everything can be written via sums and products of the class of $X$ and elements of $K$.

Finally, you can really think of  $K[X]/(f)$ as $K[\alpha]$ where $\alpha$ is some root of $f$. The point of considering $K[X]/(f)$ is that in abstract it is not at all clear if there is a root of $f$ or from which other field it should be taken. Indeed, the construction $K[X]/(f)$ can be used  to show that every polynomial over a field $K$ has a root in some extension field  of $K$.

Answer (score 1):

A very direct way to see that $K[X]/(f)$ is an algebraic extension of $K$ is as follows:

- First of all $K[X]/(f)$ is a *field*. Indeed, $K[X]$ is a ring and $(f)$ is a *maximal ideal* in it (because $f$ is irreducible), hence the quotient is a field
- $K[X]/(f)$ is an *extension* of $K$. Indeed, the canonical map $K\to K[X]/(f)$, $a\mapsto a+(f)$ is a ring homomorphism and as $K$ is a fiueld it can only have two possible kernels: $\{0\}$ or $K$. The latter case does not occur because certainly $f\nmid 1$
- The extension is *algebraic*. Indeed, field extensions are also vector spaces over the smaller field. Here, $K[X]/(f)$ is clearly spanned by $1+(f),X+(f),X^2+(f),\ldots,X^{\deg f-1}+(f)$, hence finite dimensional. Thus for any $\alpha\in K[X]/(f)$, the (infinitely many) powers of $\alpha$ are $K$-linearly dependent, and any such linear dependence relation shows that $\alpha$ is the root of a polynomial in $K[X]$.

Comment: So $E/F$ is algebraic $\iff$ $E$ is a $F-$vector space of finite dimension ?